# How to move code of an inner class to different file (Python)?

Tags: python, class, module

Assume I have some class with an inner class:

```
class A:
   class B:
      ...
   ...
```

I would like to implement class `B` in a different file than the code for class `A` to increase readability.

How can this be accomplished?

---

EDIT:  I don't want `B` to be accessible in any way other than `A.B`.

Comment: Select, cut, create new file, paste, save?

Comment: @poke - but wouldn't that make B a completely different class? I want it to be accessible through A.B.

Comment: You can just define the *class* outside; `A` can still create new instances of `B` so they're accessible by `a.b` or whatever you've named your instances.

Comment: @TidB - I'm not sure I understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @R B I basically said what @sweeneyrod has written in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

b_class.py:

```
class _B:
    ...
```

a_class.py:

```
import b_class

class A:
    B = b_class._B
    ...
```

One of the principles of Pythonic OOP is "we're all consenting adults here". This means that you don't usually want to forcibly hide information. Leading underscores used to mean "don't use this", but they don't prevent things being accessed.

Although generally you don't need to nest classes like this. What do you want to do this for? There is probably a better solution.

Comment: But that would make B accessible not via A.B (using `_B`), which is something I don't want.

Comment: @RB Are you coming from a Java or C++ background? The protection concept (private, protected, public) does not translate to Python. As sweeneyrod, noted there is probably a better solution if you tell us **why** you want that nesting scope.

Comment: @msw - My `A` class is a Hidden Markov Model and `B` is a state in the model. I'm the only one using the code so it's more for my readability more than anything else. Sure I could have created an external class `HMM_Node` or something like that, but it is much clearer to be when it is an inner class. I don't think it is right to argue that nested class are a bad solution, even if it simply helps me maintain the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does seem as if you have mutually contradictory desires: "I would like to implement class B in a different file than the code for class A" versus "but it is much clearer to me when it is an inner class.". Obviously, both cannot be fulfilled.

Comment: @msw - I don't see the contradiction here. By inner class I mean I would like to access it via `HMM.State`, where `HMM` is the outer class and `State` is the inner class. This is accessed by a code of a more complicated algorithm which uses this structure. I would like to be able to use it like this and view/edit the classes in different files whenever I wish to, why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be working on a C++ `namespace` or Java `package` declaration principle which is not the Python model. The implementation of namespaces in Python is based the file name. Objects (classes, functions, etc.) are named by the source file that contains them.

You want HMM and HMM.State? Fine, do as sweeneyrod suggested and use the **has-a** object composition principle:

```
import states

class HMM {
    def __init__(self):
        self.markov_stuff = stuff
        self.state = states.State(more_stuff)
        …
}
```

That's how it works, where `states.py` contains the definition of `class State`.

If you want to make it look more "integrated" you could use `from states import State` yielding

```
from states import State

class HMM {
    def __init__(self):
        self.markov_stuff = stuff
        self.state = State(more_stuff)
        …
}
```

That gives you separate files: markov.py and states.py with the syntax of one less level of `.` indirection.

If you desire something else, either you get into confusing (and unconventional) module dictionary munging which is not recommended. Different languages allow expression of intent in different ways, and this is the pythonic way.